# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm using worklight studio within eclipse. I created a new workspace and created a new worklight project without changing anything in the basic project. 
When I run the app in the preview mode in Chrome i can see this error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:10080/appTest/apps/services/preview/appTest/common/1.0/default/worklight/messages/it-/messages.json

wlclient init started
before: initOptions.onSuccess
after: initOptions.onSuccess
wlclient init success
```

How do i solve it?
thanks!

Comment: I don't see this error; please upload to Dropbox a Worklight project showing this error so it could be debugged.

Comment: here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/e078w3mk2wkgr88/WLappTest.zip

Comment: I don't see anything altered in this project... can you elaborate on what you're actually doing...?

Comment: I simply create a new worklight project-> hybrid Application-> give it a name. After the project is created I right-click on apps/myAppname then Run as->preview. At this point I can see "hello worklight" on my browser and the console shows the error above.

It could maybe a problem with the websphere server?

Comment: Still do not see the error; make sure to first run as > run on Worklight Development Server and then visit Worklight Console, and click on "preview web resources". alternatively, try adding an environment > build and try again.

Comment: which worklight version is this?

Comment: The version of Worklight is 6.2

Comment: Still unable to reproduce... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In Eclipse, go to Help > Check for updates

   This should update Worklight Studio to a build from August 1st 2014, containing several fixes including one related to previewing applications.

   - PI21516 APPLICATION PREVIEW PROVIDING INCORRECT HTML AFTER SUCCESSIVE REFRESHES
   - PI22595 WHEN SWITCHING WORKLIGHT VERSIONS FREQUENTLY, A DEVELOPER COULD INTERMITTENTLY SEE WLJQ.JS DROPPED DURING PREVIEW.
2. Use a fresh workspace

BTW, do let me know if there is anything language-specific in your application or Chrome installation... the error message is strange, but does mention it-/messages.json... not sure where it is coming from, but it may be due to some language related issue, so, let me know.